# How to solve unknow type problem when load a Xmal file

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am facing this error, "Cannot create unknown Type '{clr- namespace:ActivityLibrary1;assembly=ActivityLibrary1}MyActivity1'" while trying to load a worklfow from Xaml file. I am trying to load Xaml from a class library project. ActivityLibrary1 is library that contains custom activity. I tried to resolve assembly at runtime by handling the currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(MyResolveEventHandler) event. The assembly which it is unable to find is System.Xaml.Resources. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by putting assembly in Clr 4.0's GAC