# Error 'TF215097:...Cannot create unknown type for...' custom CodeActivity

Tags: xaml, tfs, workflow-foundation, tfsbuild

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TFS 2010 Custom Build Activity TF215097 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910983/tfs-2010-custom-build-activity-tf215097-error)

I'm trying to create a CustomActivity to run after each successful build.

I've followed the exact steps of several tutorials

1. http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/archive/2010/03/08/lessons-learnt-building-a-custom-activity-to-run-typemock-isolator-in-vs2010-team-build.aspx
2. http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/29/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-4-Create-your-own-activity.aspx
3. http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=522&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

And all have lead me to the same result - The build fails after several seconds with this error:

```
TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition 
\MyCompany\Dev - Client: Cannot create unknown type '{clr-
namespace:BuildTasks.Activities;assembly=BuildTasks}TFSBuildLocalizer'.
```

I came down to a point where I have removed all custom references I had in the CodeActivity project and commented out all of the code.

I have added the output dll to the TFS, and I have the following post build script in the project's properties:

```
"$(DevEnvDir)\TF.exe" checkout "$/MyCompany/Development/Djenne/Dev/Tools/BuildProcess/Output/$(TargetFileName)"
copy /Y "$(TargetPath)" "C:\tfs2010\MyCompany\Dev\Tools\BuildProcess\Output\$(TargetFileName)"
"$(DevEnvDir)\TF.exe" checkin "$/MyCompany/Development/Djenne/Dev/Tools/BuildProcess/Output/$(TargetFileName)"
```

I've made sure that the namespace in the workflow xaml is correct for the custom CodeActivity.

I have no idea what else can I try,

Please help!

Thanks,

**EDIT: I'm adding more descriptions about what I've already tried:**

The CodeActivity class already have the attribute:

```
[BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.All)]
```

The CodeActivity class is contained inside an Activity Library project.
Here is the ProjectTypeGuids tag inside the csproj file:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{32f31d43-81cc-4c15-9de6-3fc5453562b6};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

In the custom workflow xaml I've added my CodeActivity right after "Get Impacted Tests, Index Sources and Publish Symbols"

I currently don'e have any InArgument nor OutArgument in my CodeActivity.

These are the references in my CodeActivity project:

- Microsoft.CSharp
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client
- System
- System.Activities
- System.Core
- System.Data
- System.Data.DataSetExtensions
- System.Xaml
- System.Xml
- System.Xml.Linq
- WindowsBase

In "Build Controller Properties" I have set the "Version control path to custom assemblies" with the same TFS path as my post build script:
$/MyCompany/Development/Djenne/DEV/Tools/BuildProcess/Output

In my Build Definition I've set "Build process template" with my custom workflow xaml.

Thank you guys for the answers, do you have any more thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem...

Comment: For me nothing of that answers here has helped, but this one will help:

http://www.hugohaggmark.com/2011/09/08/stuck-on-cannot-create-unknown-type-clr-namespace-in-tfs-build/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I got this thing figured out.

Here's what worked for me:

I've installed my dll to the GAC in the build server, ran the build and suddenly it worked!

```
gacutil.exe /i buildtasks
```

Afterwards, I've uninstalled the dll from the GAC, and it keeps working even still.

```
gacutil.exe /u buildtasks
```

Another thing, my project had several references which I also had to checkin in the same directory as the CodeActivity dll itself.
So to do that I've changed my project's post build script:

```
cd "C:\tfs2010\Djenne\Dev\Tools\BuildProcess\Output\"
"$(DevEnvDir)\TF.exe" checkout "$/TradeNetworks/Development/Djenne/Dev/Tools/BuildProcess/Output/*.*"
xcopy "$(TargetDir)*.*" "C:\tfs2010\Djenne\Dev\Tools\BuildProcess\Output\" /E /R /C /Y
```

The only thing left to do now is to figure out how to debug this damn thing.
But that's an issue for another question.

Thanks to everybody who helped,

Hope this will help anyone in the future as well.

**EDIT:**

**One more thing I've noticed is every time I edit my custom workflow, it regenerates the xaml and removes the ";assembly=BuildTasks" suffix from the custom CodeActivity namespace (xmlns).
So after every change I need to edit the xaml to fix it over and over again, otherwise the same error reoccurres.**

Comment: +1 for noting the issue in your edit - I too have to manually add in the ;assembly= bit to my xmlns:local attribute

Comment: Edit to bold the edit, to save others from banging their heads against the wall like I just did.

Comment: The edit in this answer was key to my success +1 to beardwizzle and Captain.

Comment: Added Edit #2 for a more workable solution.

Comment: Since Edit #2 was rejected:  The ";assembly=BuildTasks" portion is removed from XMLNS if the build task is in the same project as the workflow XAML you are editing. Using two separate projects (one to edit the build template, one to create custom build activities) resolves this issue and allows you to edit the workflow in the designer with having to manually edit the XAML after each change.

Answer (score 4):

You have to decorate your class with the BuildActivity attribute. See http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/27/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-7-How-is-the-custom-assembly-found.aspx at the bottom. There is an UPDATE section with more information.

Comment: Ewald, I already have this attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Where is assembly of your CustomActivity? You must add this assembly to source control and introduce it to the Build Controller you are using. For this:

1. Right click on Builds node.
2. Select Manage build controllers.
3. Click properties.
4. In the "Version control path to custom assemblies" section, introduce your assembly.

Comment: @Captain, Are you sure you have checked-in that latest assembly?

Comment: This is weird explained on MSDN. You should not add only the project/solution to source control but also the assembly file that contains the activity. I know, TFS should figure it out by itself but it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem. The reason was that I had compiled the library with the custom activities against the x86 platform and the Build Controller was running off of a 64-bit Windows 2008 VM. Switching the target platform to AnyCPU allowed the build controller to immediately utilize the library without having to add it to the GAC.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to the output dll being in TFS.

What could happen is the following:

- TFS does a get latest
- The output dll is fetched and is read only
- TFS tries to build
- The build tries to write to the dll
- Since the dll is read only you get an exception

Comment: Why would the TFS try to write on the dll???
Besides, in that case the exception should've been some kind of IO exception and not "Cannot create unknown type"
Don't you think?

Comment: Not TFS, the build, it builds the source code and outputs the dll to the same location as the dll that is checked in to TFS. It is very often that the error messages from TFS are totally wrong

Comment: Ok, so what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Move the checkout from postbuild to prebuild, this will make the file writable