# TF215097 Custom Build Activities using Com Interop on 64 bitsTF215097: An error occurred w

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition {DefinitionName}: The invocation of the constructor on type 'Classname' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.

OK some had already answered this very well:
[TFS 2010 Custom Build Activity TF215097 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910983/tfs-2010-custom-build-activity-tf215097-error)

I had the same issue before and corrected them by adding the correct attribute:
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildActivity( Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.HostEnvironmentOption.Agent )

My build is running well on x86 machine but give the error on 64 bit build controller or agent.

The Context :

I created several Build Activities. One of this activity is a Visual Build Pro runner activity. I referenced the Visual Build Professional 6 Server Object. (We have several project and could not update it... at this point)
When I build the assembly VS 2010 generate Native.{MyAssemblyName}.manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity name="Native.EMI.TeamFoundation.Build" version="1.0.0.0" type="win32" />
  <file name="VisBuildSvr.dll" asmv2:size="712904">
    <hash xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
      <dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
      </dsig:Transforms>
      <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
      <dsig:DigestValue>aePKKx7BgE7vN7OjQqwrQ2bvex8=</dsig:DigestValue>
    </hash>
    <typelib tlbid="{c48285d5-e97e-4824-9e14-faf8124b00a4}" version="1.0" helpdir="C:\Program Files (x86)\VisBuildPro6\System\VisBuildPro.chm" resourceid="0" flags="HASDISKIMAGE" />
    <comClass clsid="{d87ad38d-99d9-4e04-9505-696c3afde66c}" threadingModel="Both" tlbid="{c48285d5-e97e-4824-9e14-faf8124b00a4}" progid="VisBuildSvr6.Application" description="Visual Build Pro 6 server application component" />
    <comClass clsid="{1cc058ff-793f-4560-9fad-48d88db93ca9}" threadingModel="Free" tlbid="{c48285d5-e97e-4824-9e14-faf8124b00a4}" progid="VisBuildSvr6.Builder" description="Visual Build core builder component (MTA)" />
    <comClass clsid="{5ef3f30b-278b-4796-8f23-41fdd5ddc96c}" threadingModel="Both" tlbid="{c48285d5-e97e-4824-9e14-faf8124b00a4}" progid="VisBuildSvr6.BuilderSTA" description="Visual Build core builder component (MTA/STA)" />
  </file>
</assembly>
```

And Interop.VisBuildSvr.dll assembly

When I trig a build on a Windows 64 bit Build Controller and Agent on the same machine I have the TF error. 
I tried to attach the debugger on the controller and I am able to see the first error :

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.VisBuildSvr, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d64ea679b6fd0408' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

That file is on my custom assemblies folder on TFS and also on the BuildController and BuildAgent folder.

Thanks

Comment: I finally found the cause. I use com 32 interop in my custom activity.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, it looks like you got it working by configuring your build to invoke the 32-bit version of MSBuild. Is that right?

Comment: No I did not rely on msbuild. 
The problem was with the workflow template and TFS Service Host who try to load all the assemblies who have a [BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.Controller)] attribute.
To get rid of that, I separated the class who use the 32 bit Visual Build pro Interop in a separate assembly and did not use that attribute. At run time I check the host environment and create the 32 bits Interop class only on 32 bits system.
I also created a 64 bits class who use the Visual Build pro 8 64 bit interop.

Comment: The biggest problem was when my Visual Build pro activity class was in my main activity assembly. Because of the attribute, TFS load the assembly automatically and gave an error TF215097. When I put my visual build activity in another assembly, I finally had an error about the 32 bit interop. Sorry I did not keep the error message.